# changing UIActionSheetStyle makes no difference in iOS7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7, uiactionsheet

Is this some bug in iOS7?  I took screenshots with

```
UIActionSheetStyleBlackOpaque,
UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent,
UIActionSheetStyleAutomatic,
UIActionSheetStyleDefault.
```

It's all the same.

```
UIActionSheet *action = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
[action setActionSheetStyle:UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent]; // changing enumerable here shows exactly same result
[action showInView:_controlsView];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TransitionGuide/TempViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174-CH11-SW1) `UIActionSheetStyle` constants are unused in iOS 7.